# Почему в скобочках while пишется true?

Tags: javascript

```
var sum = 0;
while (true) {
  var value = +prompt("Введите число", '');
  if (!value) break; // (*)
  sum += value;
}
alert( 'Сумма: ' + sum );
```

Comment: Бесконечный цикл. Но это плохой пример кода. Так делать не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

В данном коде `while (true)` означает, что цикл будет выполняться бесконечно, т.к. он выполняется до тех пор пока условие `true`, а в нашем случае оно будет `true` всегда.

Для выхода из цикла предусмотрена конструкция: `if (!value) break;`, т.е. если пользователь ничего не ввел, то происходит выход из цикла оператором `break`.

Comment: _ничего не ввел_, или ввел 0, или не число